# OAuth - Facebook MissingTokenError: (missing_token) Missing access token parameter

Tags: flask, oauth

I am using [Flask_Dance](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension to login using my facebook account, the app always returns an error that says:

`oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MissingTokenError
MissingTokenError: (missing_token) Missing access token parameter.`

Here are my configurations:

```
from flask_dance.consumer.backend.sqla import SQLAlchemyBackend
from flask_dance.contrib.facebook import make_facebook_blueprint

facebook_blueprint = make_facebook_blueprint(
    client_id=app.config['FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'],
    client_secret=app.config['FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    scope=["public_profile"]
)

app.register_blueprint(facebook_blueprint)

@oauth_authorized.connect_via(facebook_blueprint)
def facebook_logged_in(blueprint, token):
    resp = blueprint.session.get('me?fields={fields}'.format(fields='id,email,picture,first_name,last_name,verified'))
    if resp.ok:
        account_info_json = resp.json()
        email = account_info_json['email']

        query = User.query.filter_by(email=email)

        try:

            user = query.one()
            user.image = account_info_json['picture']['data']['url']
            db.session.commit()

        except NoResultFound:
            user = User()
            user.image = account_info_json['picture']['data']['url']
            user.fullname = account_info_json['name']
            user.username = account_info_json['name']
            user.email = email
            if account_info_json['verified'] == True:
                user.active = True
                user.confirmed = True
                user.subscribed = True

            default_role = Role.query.filter_by(name="default").first()
            user.roles.append(default_role)

            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

        login_user(user, remember=True)

        identity_changed.send(
            current_app._get_current_object(),
            identity=Identity(user.id)
        )

facebook_blueprint.backend = SQLAlchemyBackend(OAuth, db.session, user=current_user)
```

In the url, i can see the token that returned from the app included right after the **code** parameter like this:

[https://localhost:5000/facebook/authorized?code=ACCESS_TOKEN#*=*](https://localhost:5000/facebook/authorized?code=ACCESS_TOKEN#_=_)

Here are the versions of the extensions:

```
oauthlib==3.0.0
Flask_Dance==1.2.0
```

The callback:

```
@oauth_blueprint.route("/facebook")
def facebook_login():
    if not facebook.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("facebook.login"))
    if facebook.authorized:
        next = request.url
        if next is not None:
            return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('home.index'))
    return redirect(url_for("facebook.login"))
```

**contrib/facebook.py**:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from flask_dance.consumer import OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint
from functools import partial
from flask.globals import LocalProxy, _lookup_app_object
try:
    from flask import _app_ctx_stack as stack
except ImportError:
    from flask import _request_ctx_stack as stack

def make_facebook_blueprint(
        client_id=None, client_secret=None, scope=None, redirect_url=None,
        redirect_to=None, login_url=None, authorized_url=None,
        session_class=None, backend=None):
    facebook_bp = OAuth2ConsumerBlueprint("facebook", __name__,
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        scope=scope,
        base_url='https://graph.facebook.com/v{version}/'.format(version='3.0'),
        authorization_url='https://www.facebook.com/v{version}/dialog/oauth'.format(version='3.0'),
        token_url='https://graph.facebook.com/v{version}/oauth/access_token'.format(version='3.0'),
        redirect_url= redirect_url,
        redirect_to=redirect_to,
        login_url=login_url,
        authorized_url=authorized_url,
        session_class=session_class,
        backend=backend,
    )
    facebook_bp.from_config["client_id"] = "FACEBOOK_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID"
    facebook_bp.from_config["client_secret"] = "FACEBOOK_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET"

    @facebook_bp.before_app_request
    def set_applocal_session():
        ctx = stack.top
        ctx.facebook_oauth = facebook_bp.session

    return facebook_bp

facebook = LocalProxy(partial(_lookup_app_object, "facebook_oauth"))
```

Comment: Show your code where you are processing the callback with ACCESS_TOKEN

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: 1) Where are you using `facebook_oauth`? 2) What does `facebook_bp.session.auth` contain? 3) Where are you calling `set_applocal_session()` 4) What line of code generates `oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MissingTokenError`?

Comment: 1) it contains the facebook_bp.session object
2) None
3) Before the first app request
4) https://pastebin.com/ciKWvxUA

Comment: What really makes it more weird is i have another application using the same configurations but a different oauth facebook app and it works just perfect!!!!

Comment: I tried to downgrade the extensions version , maybe its a bug in the newer versions, but without avail!!!

Comment: For my question #1. Where are you using `facebook_bp.session`? I know what it is. #2. If `auth` contains `None`, then your authentication failed - this might indicate why you are getting the error about `MissingTokenError`. #4) I don't have time (too lazy) to map a stack trace to your source code. Show me in your question where this error is generated in your code (not the library's code).

Comment: For your comment "What really makes it more weird ...". I think your real problem is either a misconfiguration of your Client Secrets or the User Authentication is failing. See if you get the same error with bogus credentials.

Comment: Thats right! i've tried another client secret and it worked, but i am sure that my new app secret is right!!!

Comment: Whould you believe this, i just added the `u` before defining the app id an secret and it worked!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the library expecting Python 3 Unicode strings.

The solution is to add `u` before the Client ID and Client Secret strings to make the strings Unicode encoded.